# Using Count Distinct with Pivot in Snowflake

Tags: pivot, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to do a pivoting on column `Join_mon` and get aggregate count for each `ID` , as shown in following query;

```
select *
from CTE3
pivot(COUNT(DISTINCT platform_payer_name) for Join_Mon in (
 '2021-03-01',
 '2021-02-01',
  '2021-01-01',
 '2020-12-01'

        ))
  as p
order by ID
)
```

As you can see I am trying to get distinct count her for the column `platform_payer_name`. But it is giving the following error;

```
SQL compilation error: syntax error line 48 at position 16 unexpected 'DISTINCT'
```

I am quite positive `DISTINCT` works with `COUNT` in snowflake. Can I get some help why it is failing here. Help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you show us input data and expected results? Pivot gets confused with this syntax, but we could find an alternative way to make this work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so making some fake data that maps to your pivot, albeit I dropped the excessive paren

```
with cte3(id, platform_payer_name, Join_Mon) as (
    select * from values
        (1,'aa', '2021-03-01'),
        (1,'aa', '2021-03-01'),
        (1,'aa', '2021-03-01'),
        (1,'aa', '2021-02-01'),
        (2,'bb', '2012-03-01'),
        (2,'cc', '2020-12-01')
)
select *
from CTE3 AS c
pivot(COUNT(c.platform_payer_name) for c.Join_Mon in (
         '2021-03-01',
         '2021-02-01',
         '2021-01-01',
         '2020-12-01' )
) as p
order by id;
```

gives:

```
ID  '2021-03-01'    '2021-02-01'    '2021-01-01'    '2020-12-01'
1   3               1               0               0
2   0               0               0               1
```

so makes sense you want `distinct` in there

but it seems it's not supported..

so while it's somewhat cut'n'paste error prone, it does "work":

```
with cte3(id, platform_payer_name, Join_Mon) as (
    select * from values
        (1,'aa', '2021-03-01'),
        (1,'aa', '2021-03-01'),
        (1,'aa', '2021-03-01'),
        (1,'aa', '2021-02-01'),
        (2,'bb', '2012-03-01'),
        (2,'cc', '2020-12-01')
)
select id
    ,count(distinct(iff(Join_Mon='2021-03-01',platform_payer_name,null))) as "2021-03-01"
    ,count(distinct(iff(Join_Mon='2021-02-01',platform_payer_name,null))) as "2021-02-01"
    ,count(distinct(iff(Join_Mon='2021-01-01',platform_payer_name,null))) as "2021-01-01"
    ,count(distinct(iff(Join_Mon='2020-12-01',platform_payer_name,null))) as "2020-12-01"
from CTE3 AS c
group by 1 order by 1;
```

gives:

```
ID  2021-03-01  2021-02-01  2021-01-01  2020-12-01
1   1           1           0           0
2   0           0           0           1
```

which works because pivot is doing two task, the first is moving values into columns if matching the input, thus that is the same as:

```
with cte3(id, platform_payer_name, Join_Mon) as (
select * from values
    (1,'aa', '2021-03-01'),
    (1,'aa', '2021-03-01'),
    (1,'aa', '2021-03-01'),
    (1,'aa', '2021-02-01'),
    (2,'bb', '2012-03-01'),
    (2,'cc', '2020-12-01')
)
select id
    ,iff(Join_Mon='2021-03-01',platform_payer_name,null) as "2021-03-01"
    ,iff(Join_Mon='2021-02-01',platform_payer_name,null) as "2021-02-01"
    ,iff(Join_Mon='2021-01-01',platform_payer_name,null) as "2021-01-01"
    ,iff(Join_Mon='2020-12-01',platform_payer_name,null) as "2020-12-01"
from CTE3 AS c
order by 1;
```

which gives:

```
ID, 2021-03-01, 2021-02-01, 2021-01-01, 2020-12-01
1,  aa,         NULL,       NULL,       NULL
1,  aa,         NULL,       NULL,       NULL
1,  aa,         NULL,       NULL,       NULL
1,  NULL,       aa,         NULL,       NULL
2,  NULL,       NULL,       NULL,       NULL
2,  NULL,       NULL,       NULL,       cc
```

which can then have a `count(distinct x)` ran over each column.

```
select id
    ,count(distinct("2021-03-01")) as "2021-03-01"
    ,count(distinct("2021-02-01")) as "2021-02-01"
    ,count(distinct("2021-01-01")) as "2021-01-01"
    ,count(distinct("2020-12-01")) as "2020-12-01"
from (
    select id
        ,iff(Join_Mon='2021-03-01',platform_payer_name,null) as "2021-03-01"
        ,iff(Join_Mon='2021-02-01',platform_payer_name,null) as "2021-02-01"
        ,iff(Join_Mon='2021-01-01',platform_payer_name,null) as "2021-01-01"
        ,iff(Join_Mon='2020-12-01',platform_payer_name,null) as "2020-12-01"
    from CTE3 AS c
)
group by id
order by id;
```

or can be done inline as I showed in the first answer.

Answer (score 0):

Snowflake supports [COUNT_IF](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/count_if.html):

```
SELECT id,
       COUNT_IF(join_mon='2021-03-01') AS "2021-03-01",
       COUNT_IF(join_mon='2021-02-01') AS "2021-02-01",
       COUNT_IF(join_mon='2021-01-01') AS "2021-01-01"
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT id, platform_name, join_mon FROM cte) s
GROUP BY id
ORDER BY id;
```